# Hide menu on click of button

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap drop-down. What I'm trying to achieve is once you click on the button the menu appears but when you click on the button again the menu doesn't hide. I want the menu to hide on click of the button. The method I tried didn't work and I think there should be a more suitable way to hide the menu on click of the button. How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

```js
$('.dropdown button').on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).attr('class').split(" ").pop() == 'show') {
    //not working menu is getting hidden before showen
    $(this).parents('.dropdown').find('ul').hide()
  }
});
```

```css
.dropdown {
  margin-left: 40%;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  transform: translate(calc(-50% + 20px), 40px) !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.0.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-3B6NwesSXE7YJlcLI9RpRqGf2p/EgVH8BgoKTaUrmKNDkHPStTQ3EyoYjCGXaOTS" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-bell"></i>
                    </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item">option 1</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item">option 2</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item">option 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you prefer using the "toggle" instead?

```
   $(function () {
      $("button").click(function () {
      $(".dropdown-menu").toggle();
  });
});
```

Comment: when I use the method you suggested the dropdown menu is shown but its alignment is messed up and as soon as you scroll the alignment gets fixed. It's a weird bug you know why that's happening?

Comment: With your CSS, the menu is well aligned at this end. Or could it be that you changed your css?

Comment: it's a weird bug. I created a new question about it can you take a look at it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72682150/drop-down-alignment-issues