# drop down alignment issues

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I have 3 bootstrap drop down elements. The first 2's toggle are not being controlled by jquery but the 3rd one is getting hidden and shown using jquery. Now the problem is when I click on the first 2 dropdown buttons their menus will show aligned correctly but the 3rd one has problems. The first problem it has is that its menu won't show on the first click when you click it the second time the menu will show. The second problem it has is, the position of the menu of the 3rd dropdown is not right. It appears on the wrong position but once you scroll on the body the position gets fixed. I did some debugging and found out that when removing the other 2 drop down elements the 3rd dropdown works fine and the second problem is fixed. I don't get what the problem is all I did is control its toggle with jquery. How can I fix these problems? Thanks in advance.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".account button").click(function() {
    $(".account .dropdown-menu").toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: right;
  align-items: center;
  column-gap: 4%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20vh;
  background-color: gold;
}

.header .dropdown {
  border: none;
}

.header .dropdown button:focus {
  box-shadow: none;
}

.header .dropdown.account ul{
    transform: translate(0px, 40px) !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.0.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-3B6NwesSXE7YJlcLI9RpRqGf2p/EgVH8BgoKTaUrmKNDkHPStTQ3EyoYjCGXaOTS" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="header">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>
                    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a class="dropdown-item switchProfile">option 1</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item myAccount">option 2</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item logOut">option 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>
                    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a class="dropdown-item switchProfile">option 1</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item myAccount">option 2</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item logOut">option 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown account">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i>
                    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a class="dropdown-item switchProfile">option 1</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item myAccount">option 2</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item logOut">option 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dude Check if this is working for you.

```css
.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  column-gap: 4%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20vh;
  background-color: gold;
}

.header .dropdown {
  border: none;
}

.header .dropdown button:focus {
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Dropdown</title>
    
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.0.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-3B6NwesSXE7YJlcLI9RpRqGf2p/EgVH8BgoKTaUrmKNDkHPStTQ3EyoYjCGXaOTS" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header">
     <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>
                    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a class="dropdown-item switchProfile">option 1</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item myAccount">option 2</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item logOut">option 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>
                    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a class="dropdown-item switchProfile">option 1</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item myAccount">option 2</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item logOut">option 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown account">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i>
                    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a class="dropdown-item switchProfile">option 1</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item myAccount">option 2</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item logOut">option 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
    
    <!-- Js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to add that JavaScript code. Check it will work properly without that.

Comment: i need that jquery code because i want to hide the visible menu on click of the button. Without it, i.e the first 2 drop downs, if you click on the button after a visible menu it won't hide the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Check this Example `transform: translate(0px, 40px)` add in this class `header .dropdown.account ul` it is working fine now.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".account button").click(function() {
    $(".account .dropdown-menu").toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  column-gap: 4%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20vh;
  background-color: gold;
}

.header .dropdown {
  border: none;
}

.header .dropdown button:focus {
  box-shadow: none;
}

.header .dropdown.account ul{
      transform: translate(0px, 40px) !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.0.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-3B6NwesSXE7YJlcLI9RpRqGf2p/EgVH8BgoKTaUrmKNDkHPStTQ3EyoYjCGXaOTS" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="header">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>
                    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a class="dropdown-item switchProfile">option 1</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item myAccount">option 2</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item logOut">option 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>
                    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a class="dropdown-item switchProfile">option 1</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item myAccount">option 2</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item logOut">option 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown account">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i>
                    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a class="dropdown-item switchProfile">option 1</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item myAccount">option 2</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item logOut">option 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I already thought about that but if the dropdown button is aligned to the right half the menu will be out of the body container I could add more px to the translate but that won't be ideal for responsive design. Run my code above again I have aligned the button to the right. If you click on the 3rd button half the menu is out body

Comment: Dude if it is right align then you need to change css on   

".header .dropdown.account ul{ transform: translate(-120px, 40px) !important;}"

Comment: I just explained why that's a Bad Idea. It's not responsive!! If for example, the menu is 60px wide, and your device width changes the translate wont update automatically thus misaligning the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Then you can add this CDN. It will solve the issue.

```
<script
   src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
      crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.0.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-3B6NwesSXE7YJlcLI9RpRqGf2p/EgVH8BgoKTaUrmKNDkHPStTQ3EyoYjCGXaOTS" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script
  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
<style>
.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  column-gap: 4%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20vh;
  background-color: gold;
}

.header .dropdown {
  border: none;
}

.header .dropdown button:focus {
  box-shadow: none;
}

.header .dropdown.account ul{
      transform: translate(0px, 40px) !important;
}
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".btn btn-secondary").click(function(){
    $(".dropdown-menu").toggle();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>
                    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a class="dropdown-item switchProfile">option 1</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item myAccount">option 2</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item logOut">option 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>
                    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a class="dropdown-item switchProfile">option 1</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item myAccount">option 2</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item logOut">option 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown account">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i>
                    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a class="dropdown-item switchProfile">option 1</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item myAccount">option 2</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item logOut">option 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Check, it's working.

Comment: can you make it runable please

Comment: also this won't work. I explained why on @Upendra Nath Dubey answer